# npm Error when i want to creat my react application

Tags: javascript

I would like to have your help during the creation of my react application I have an error message that here:

Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17763.1098]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

```
C:\Users\Godson>npm --v
6.14.4

C:\Users\Godson>npm install create-react-app -g
C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@3.4.1
added 10 packages from 6 contributors, removed 2 packages and updated 34 packages in 56.528s

C:\Users\Godson>npm install --global npm@latest
C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.14.4
added 435 packages from 869 contributors in 93.752s

C:\Users\Godson>npm install create-react-app -g
C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@3.4.1
updated 1 package in 20.534s

C:\Users\Godson>create-react-app jeux

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Godson\jeux.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...w3bl8EeB3TQE8OQWwKsHA'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-18T09_01_02_112Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting jeux/ from C:\Users\Godson
Done.

C:\Users\Godson>npx create-react-app jeux

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Godson\jeux.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...w3bl8EeB3TQE8OQWwKsHA'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Godson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-18T09_14_27_921Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting jeux/ from C:\Users\Godson
Done.

C:\Users\Godson>
```

I tried `npm cache clean --force` but still the same problem
this is the message that appeared after this command

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing
```

an explanation for this problem will be welcome, thank you

Comment: Have you checked your package.json file to be valid JSON?

Comment: how to check it ?

Comment: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...w3bl8EeB3TQE8OQWwKsHA'